# Loading Images into Canvas Tags Systematically

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, for-loop

I have a function which makes any desired amount of "div" tags with a "canvas" tag within them. Now, I'm having trouble trying to load individual photos from an array into  those "canvas" tags.

I have an array which has various photo directories stored within it, and I want to say load the first picture in that array into the first canvas tag, and the second image in that array into the second canvas tag, and so on.

I got these snippets of code from around the web, and just editted it to try and adhere it to my project.

This creates the div and canvas tags.

```
for (var item = 0; item < 3; item++) {
if (item % 5 == 0) {
    document.write(item);
}
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute('id', 100+item);
document.body.appendChild(div);

var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
canv.setAttribute('width', 400);
canv.setAttribute('height', 400);
canv.setAttribute('id', item);
div.appendChild(canv);
}
```

This is to load an image in a specified canvas tag. I'm aware that the key to answering my question lies somewhere in this part of the code, but I'm quite new to this process, and I don't have very good knowledge of methods associated with the canvas tag and image loading.

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){

var can = document.getElementById('0');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');            //creates canvas and image data
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var imgdata = ctx.getImageData(0,0, img.width, img.height);
var data = imgdata.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to create new div containing new canvas containing an image from an array**

Assume that you have loaded all your images into an array called imgs.

Then this loop will create a new div containing a new canvas with an image from imgs:

```
  for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){

      // create a new div
      var newDiv=document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.id="div"+i;
      newDiv.style.width=imgs[i].width+"px";

      // create a new canvas
      var newCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
      newCanvas.width=imgs[i].width;
      newCanvas.height=imgs[i].height;
      newCanvas.id="canvas"+i;

      // use drawImage to draw the img[i] into the canvas
      newCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(imgs[i],0,0);

      // add new new canvas to the new div
      newDiv.appendChild(newCanvas);

      // add the new div to the document body
      document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
```

Here's code including an image preloader and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/duVYL/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

  var imageURLs=[];
  var imagesOK=0;
  var imgs=[];
  imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-1.jpg");
  imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-2.jpg");
  imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-3.jpg");
  imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house204-4.jpg");
  loadAllImages();

  function loadAllImages(){
      for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ imagesOK++; imagesAllLoaded(); }; 
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
      }      
  }


  var imagesAllLoaded = function() {
    if (imagesOK==imageURLs.length ) {
        createDivCanvasImages();
    }
  };


  function createDivCanvasImages(){

        for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
            var newDiv=document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.id="div"+i;
            newDiv.style.width=imgs[i].width+"px";
            var newCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
            newCanvas.width=imgs[i].width;
            newCanvas.height=imgs[i].height;
            newCanvas.id="canvas"+i;
            newCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(imgs[i],0,0);
            newDiv.appendChild(newCanvas);
            document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
        }
  }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**[Addition: using getImageData]**

Each new canvas has been given an id of canvas0 - canvas3.

Here's an example of how to use getImageData to manipulate the pixels.

Important!  If the images you put into the canvas don't originate on the same domain, you will get a CORS security error and the image will silently NOT be manipulated.  See:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

In the example, data[i+3]=65 will lower the alpha of the first canvas to 65/255 (25%).

```
function useGetImageData(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas0");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var data = imageData.data;

    // iterate over all pixels
    for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i+=4) {
      data[i+3]=65;
    }
    context.putImageData(imageData,0,0);        

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, not that the images are loaded into the canvas, how would I be able to use .getImageData(); and work with that data?

Comment: I made an addition to my answer showing how to use getImageData.  The example reduces the opacity of one of the canvas images to 25%.  Take careful note of CORS concerns which prohibits use of getImageData across separate domains.

Comment: the function you created in your edit brings the error message "cannot .getContext of null" when referring to your variable for context.

Comment: is it because there is no a </canvas> tag after the <canvas> tag which was created?

Comment: In my example, the canvas id's are being set to canvas0, canvas1, etc.  So be sure to get the reference to the canvas with document.getElementById('canvas0');